# Cannot take Content Type Name in SP List with Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

i am basically trying to get "Content Type Name" to another column with "When an item created" flow of Power Automate. but somehow it's not working?

is there any idea?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel that there is nothing wrong with your flow, and I have created and run it successfully. You could look at flow run history and check whether the Azim column was successfully assigned during this run.

Here are some screenshots of the success and the output of the process:

[list1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONNCY.png) [run history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNwAR.png) [Flow OUTPUTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YoTQ.png)